# PHP url is not working with slash on it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule Topics/([^/]+)$ topics.php?topic_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So all my URLs are presented like this
`Topics/Eminem`

But when i have `/` in my topic name then URL returns "Not found".
For example AC/DC becomes `Topics/AC%2FDC` but url refuses accepting it.

Comment: Should _all_ such slashes be accepted, so no llimit in depth of the path be rewriteen?

Comment: @VikingCode You want to re-think that...

Comment: Well, that's exactly what `[^/]` means: everything but slashes

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern explicitly prevents the acceptance of a further slash in the request URL, the `[^/]` describes a character set that may contain anything *but* a slash. You can modify it such that it accepts and rewrites an arbitrary character set:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Topics/(.+)/?$ topics.php?topic_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However keep in mind that this now rewrites *all* incoming requests starting with `/Topic/`.

I also modified the pattern slightly so that it is a bit more robust and will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess")...

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

UPDATE:

You added another existing rewrite rule that certainly will interfere here. Actually I would expect it to create an endless rewrite loop... I would recommend to add two conditions to that additional rule limiting the application of that rule to only those requests that do *not* immediately hit an existing file and that *do* reference an existing file with added `.php` extension. That *probably* is what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?Topics/(.+)/?$ topics.php?topic_name=$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: `^/?` is a nice addition.

Comment: @Murad You are probably looking at a cached result. Try disabling your browsers cache and/or make a deep reload instead of just refreshing the page.

Comment: I have extensions that disable cache.Also i made some changes in which other pages didn't work.I edited my answer and added one more rule that is in my htaccess file.May that be the problem?

Comment: Oh, sure, that first rule blindly rewrites _every_ incoming request to the same path with added `.php` extension. Actually I would expect that to create an endless rewrite loop...

Comment: @Murad I appended an update to the answer reflecting my thoughts on that additional rule.

Comment: Now when i get `topic_name` from URL it adds .php to it `50+cent` becomes `50 Cent.php`

Comment: About the `50+cent` case... sure, that is because the `+` character is used to code a blank character in URLs. If you want the _literal_ plus character then you need to `urlencode()` such tokens of the URL to use percent encoding.

Comment: About the appended .php extension... Indeed, both rules will get applied... I changed the order in the given example above, have a try with that.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering out slashes and complaining that slashes do not match. If you want to capture everything, just do so:

```
RewriteRule Topics/(.+)$ topics.php?topic_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the regex `Topics/([^/]+)$` the `[^/]+` part means "everything that is more than one character up to a '/' symbol". So when you try to match `Topics/AC/DC` the `[^/]+` part will only match AC. And since you added a `$` sign to the end (which means "this is the end of the input") the string won't match.

For more information see this demo: https://regex101.com/r/GJTDik/1

Answer (score 0):

> But when i have / in my topic name then URL returns "Not found".

You actually have 2 main problems here, only the first is addressed by the current answers:

1. Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `([^/]+)`) does not allow slashes (`/`) in this part of the URL, so `AC/DC` will never be matched. As stated in the other answers, you need to modify this pattern to something like `(.+)`. (Although, ideally, you should be as restrictive as possible.) NB: The *pattern* matches the %-decoded URL, so you need a regex that matches `AC/DC`, not `AC%2FDC`.
2. Apache will, by default, block any URLs that contain an encoded slash in the path part of the URL ie. `%2F`. In this situation, it will automatically return a *system generated* 404 Not Found *before* mod_rewrite gets to have a go. This is a security feature. And is most probably the result you are seeing here. If you need encoded slashes in the URL then you'll need to explicitly enable this with `AllowEncodedSlashes On` in the Apache server config (this can't be enabled in `.htaccess`).

   Note that, as mentioned, this is an *Apache generated* 404 message. If you have a custom 404 defined, then you should notice a difference.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule Topics/([^/]+)$ topics.php?topic_name=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

**UPDATE:** These rules conflict. The first rule will likely "win" for most of your URLs. You need to be more specific in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For instance, a URL like `Topics/AC%2FDC` will also match the first rule, so the second rule is never processed.